# to create an external form which can help me out in updating information of contact through email?

Tags: apex

i have just created lead through web-to-lead ,and converted lead,account and opportunity.When contact is approved by management in approval process,i just want to send an form(an email) to get more information about contact details and update it from there only.
how should i start to make a email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send an email using a workflow rule when the record is approved - [read more on how to do it](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm).

In regards to capturing the additional info there is no automated or out of the box functionality that will allow you to do so. You'll need to build something custom and there are many possible ways of doing that. Here are some examples:

- Use Appexchange app like [FormAssembly](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016ac6EAA) (cost involved)
- Host another form on the same site where the web-to-lead resides, in the email from salesforce redirect the user to that form and utilise the Salesforce APIs to update the additional contact information (time consuming to build, relevant skills and knowledge required)
- Build a public force.com site where you can redirect the contact to update their additional info (security and user experience issues)

Comment: Email would be send through workflow but how will i update the contact information from email when user will fill the details on the email.???

Comment: I've highlighted some of the options. There is no automated way of doing that.

Comment: Will formaAssembly help in doing it?

Comment: I'm not sure, you can ask them. If not then you might want to reach out to an implementation partner or a developer that is willing to assist.

Comment: okie lets find out ..